# Django dictonary not passing to template

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a calendar where I can pick a date and I'm trying to pass the date to my Django views using ajax.  That part works fine as I can print the value on the terminal. The issue I'm having is passing that date from the view to my template. Instead of passing the date, it passes `None`.

If I manually set the value of `data_input = "testing"`, it would display on the template.

views.py

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = AppointmentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = AppointmentForm
        return render(request, 'scheduling/make_appointments.html',{"form":form})
elif request.method == 'GET':
    data_input = request.GET.get('date')
    print(data_input)
    form = AppointmentForm
    args = {
        "form" : form, 
        "data_input": data_input, 
    }
    return render(request, 'scheduling/make_appointments.html', args)
```

main.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#datetimepicker").on("dp.change", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    date = $('#datepicker').serialize().replace('date=', '');
    console.log(date);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '../make_appointments/',
      data: {
        'date': date
      }
    });

  });

});
```

make_appointments.html

```
<form id="datepicker" method="get" name="select_date">
       <div id="datetimepicker">
            <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date">
       </div>
</form>

{{data_input}}
```

Edit:

`print(type(data_input))` prints `<class 'str'>`. Since the data type of `data_input` is a `string`, I don't see why it would have problems passing into the template.

Comment: How is it even reaching the `data_input` section, given that `if request.method == 'GET'` is inside of `if request.method == 'POST':`? That else condition should never be satisfied, as request methods are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Fixed the formatting.

Comment: It returns None because probably your `date = $('#datepicker').serialize().replace('date=', '');` it's being set to an emtpy string as it shows and then when you do `request.GET.get('date') it evaluates to an empty string as well. Maybe the issue is with the JS part.

Comment: Like I said, I am able to print the value on the python side. `print(data_input)` successfully prints the date that I want. I don't think the issue is with the JS.

Comment: What do you get when printing `data_input` after getting it from the request.GET?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are expecting to happen. The JS doesn't do anything with the returned response from the Ajax call, so nothing will be updated.

Comment: It depends on the date I select on the html calendar. An example would be `2019-05-15`

Comment: @DanielRoseman What do you mean? I am able to pass the date to my views. I just can't pass it from my view to my template.

Comment: Yes, because the Ajax call is not doing anything when it gets the response back from the view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Shouldn't that be handled by the view? I'm returning `data_input` to my template after I get the value from the ajax request.

Comment: I don't know how else to say it. The view returns the data to the Ajax script. The Ajax script does not do anything with it. The whole point of Ajax is that it sends a request outside of the normal browser submit flow. So it is responsible for acting on the response it receives from the backend.

Comment: @JosephCheng I'll try to put @Daniel's comment in other words: your view is actually returning an http response with the correct HTML template rendered, with date_input set to the correct value. If you open your network tab in your browser debug tools you'll see in the XHR requests that the correct response is returned. But it's returned to your ajax script, which doesn't handle it. You always need to write a `success` function to handle the data that is returned by the server. That function could then substitute the contents of a div with the contents of the response.

Comment: Ok I see what everyone is saying. I've added a success function: 

```success: function(){
        $("#date").html(date);  
      }
```

This solves one problem, but leads to another. I have a query result that needs to be rendered to the template through Django. At the end of the day, if I can render `args` to the template then all of the problems will be solved.